# setColumnOrder() on Grid in Vaadin Flow seems to cause the getSortOrder() list to increment infinitely in the event of the sort listener

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin-grid, vaadin14, vaadin20

I believe I have found a bug in the Vaadin Grid that can be replicated with the code below.

I would like to save the grid's sorting order whenever it's changed and then restore it when the grid is loaded. The main issue is that the `GridSortOrder` list just keeps incrementing in size for the event in the sort listener rather than replacing the sortorder list. I believe this is a bug within Vaadin 14-20 because it only happens if I call `setColumnOrder()` in the reset method below (removing that call it works as expected). In other words calling `setColumnOrder()` seems to add the list of `GridSortOrder` to the event in the sort listener when it should be replacing it. ***This is actually also true if you do `grid.getSortOrder()` in the listener, meaning it's not just the event but also the grid that is compromised.***

This can be replicated consistently with the code below. You will first need to change the sort order of Description column by clicking on the column header. Then just click on Reset button 5-10 times. Once this is done click on the Description column header to change the sort order one more time. The `System.out` for the listener will show a size of a list of 20 `GridSortOrder` instead of the expected 2 `GridSortOrder`. There will be replications of columns over and over.

```
Grid<Car> grid = new Grid<>();

grid.addColumn(Car::getName)
        .setSortable(true)
        .setComparator(Car::getName)
        .setKey("Name")
        .setHeader("Name");
grid.addColumn(Car::getPrice)
        .setSortable(true)
        .setComparator(Car::getPrice)
        .setKey("Price")
        .setHeader("Price");
grid.addColumn(Car::getDescription)
        .setSortable(true)
        .setComparator(Car::getDescription)
        .setKey("Description")
        .setHeader("Description");

grid.setItems(listOfCars);

grid.setColumnReorderingAllowed(true);
grid.setMultiSort(true);

grid.addSortListener(event -> {
    System.out.println("Event: " + event.getSortOrder().size() + " : " + event.isFromClient());
    System.out.println("Grid: " + grid.getSortOrder().size() + " : " + event.isFromClient());
});

defaultSort(grid);

Button resetButton = new Button("Reset", click -> {
    System.out.println("Reset: " + grid.getSortOrder().size());
    defaultSort(grid);
    grid.setColumnOrder(
            grid.getColumnByKey("Name"),
            grid.getColumnByKey("Price"),
            grid.getColumnByKey("Description"));
});

add(grid, resetButton);

private void defaultSort(Grid grid) {
    grid.sort(List.of(
            new GridSortOrder<>(grid.getColumnByKey("Name"), SortDirection.ASCENDING),
            new GridSortOrder<>(grid.getColumnByKey("Price"), SortDirection.ASCENDING)
    ));
}
```

If I remove `grid.setColumnOrder()` from the above then the `List<GridSortOrder>` works as expected and is two in the event listener. What's especially interesting is that `event.getSortOrder().size()` will increase by 2 every time the `resetButton` is clicked (but you'll only see it in the sort listener). It doesn't matter if the `setColumnOrder()` is before or after the call to `defaultSort()`.

With that in mind if you debug `grid.setColumnOrder()` it seems to call `updateClientSideSorterIndicators(sortOrder)` which is what I believe is the cause and is where it's being added to the `GridSortOrder` list. That being said I'm not sure how to proceed from here so that I can reset the grid's setting when clicking on the Reset button.

FYI: This is an issue for me because I'm trying to save the state of the Grid to the database so that when the user reloads the screen (a very complex one) all their grid settings including the sorting order, the column order, and so on are preserved. However with this bug it's impossible to save the sorting order.

PS: This seems to be true in both Vaadin 14 and Vaadin 20.

Comment: Could you add this in Vaadin's issue tracker https://github.com/vaadin/flow-components/issues

Comment: If I call grid.getSortOrder() in the SortListener I always get the correct sort order

Comment: The property of the webcomponent grid._sorters is containing the old column and direction. I'm not sure if there is an easy workaround for this.
For the reset action, you can try as a workaround to recreate the grid instead of modifying the grid.

Comment: That is my current thinking, to just reload the view or re-create the grid. I'm not sure which is less jarring when pressing the button.

Comment: @TatuLund Yes I'll submit an issue today along with a github repo with the source to replicate it.

Comment: @TatuLund It's been submitted: https://github.com/vaadin/flow-components/issues/2102 The github repo to replicate is: https://github.com/FollowSteph/VaadinGridBugReport (also included in the issue).

Comment: @TatuLund Do you know what the normal time is for any kind of action? It's been almost 2 months and it looks like the ticket hasn't even been processed...

Comment: Usually when it looks like that an issue has slipped through the cracks the best course of action is to comment on it, as I see you already did. Now that it has been properly evaluated it depends on the team's workload when they have time to actually do something about it. Comments and thumbs up reactions on the issue are a good way to show that there's active interest in getting a solution (within reason, of course, spamming the issue probably won't help).